# js function as object value receiving context of same object

Tags: javascript, this

```
var obj = {
    'obj1': {
        'key': {
            'token': 'abcd',
            'test':' test: '+token
            'search': function(s){return this.test}
        }
    }
};

alert(obj['obj1']['search'].apply(this,['some text']));
```

Inside a function, the `this` keyword refers to the function instead of the object. Well ,more or less as Felix points out.
How can I provide access inside a function to attributes belonging to the same object?
I could use closures, but I'd need to reference the keys each time, is there a more concise way to do this?

Comment: *"Inside a function, the `this` keyword refers to the function instead of the object."* That is incorrect. `this` doesn't refer to the function, unless you **explicitly** do so (which is very uncommon and looks like `func.call(func)`). The value of `this` is determined by **how the function is called**. Since you don't show how you call it, we can't really help you.

Comment: I'm using apply method of the function.

Comment: Why can't you do `obj.obj1.search('some text')`? Will you have a changing argument list that requires `apply`?

Comment: Ok, and what does `this` refer to in your example? (in `.apply(this,['some text']));`). If I understand your problem correctly, then one way would be to `.bind` the function after you created it: `obj.obj1.search = obj.obj1.search.bind(obj.obj1);`.

Comment: @apsillers: yes. I'm seperating the implementation of parametrisation from the calling routines, as these could be UI or code-driven based on context. @Felix: That's it! Modifying my call to `obj['obj1']['search'].apply(obj['obj1'],['some text'])` is the solution I need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the name of the object variable as your reference:

```
var dict={
  'key': "Something"
  'token':'abcd',
  'test':'test: '+token
  'search':function(s){return dict.test}
}
```

Comment: Not quite, and I'll modify my post, since the object itself is part of another object.